# JavaScript Scoping issue with Spring Form Action of "#"

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

This is a real mystery to me. I have inherited some code that uses "#" as the action in a Spring form tag. It took me a **long** time to isolate this, but this causes all of the local JavaScript to get scoped to window[1], and not globally.

```
<form:form name="abc" id="abc" method="post" commandName="myModel" htmlEscape="false" action="#">
```

However, when I don't specify any action, or I give it any action other than "#", then JavaScript is correctly globally scoped.

I don't have a clue as to why the action attribute affects this at all. Yes, I could specify an explicit action URL or remove it altogether, but this breaks other things in its already delicate state. I have searched Spring documentation to no avail.

Comment: what do you mean by *"get scoped to window[1], and not globally"*? window **is** the global scope. and what precisely is *"all of the local JavaScript"*?

Comment: I understand that window is the global scope, but when I use the "#" action, window also has array properties. For example, in Firebug, I can inspect **window** as well as and index of window, e.g., **window[0]** or **window[1]**. So instead of any of my global JavaScript getting scoped to **window**, it get scoped to **window[1]**. I discovered this through trial and error.